# Php formatting date

Tags: php, string, date-format

I am trying to format date using php in the below format. The following code works fine.

`echo date_format('12/04/2014:14:58', "d/M/Y\tH:i");`

I am getting the format as a single quoted string, and the below code does not the give the desired output.

```
echo date_format('12/04/2014:14:58', 'd/M/Y\tH:i');
```

Is there any way to convert a single quoted string to double quoted string ?

Thanks

Comment: do you have something like `$foo = 'd/M/Y\tH:i'` that you are not showing in your question?

Comment: Yes I am getting the format in a variable.

Comment: What does it give anyway? Any error messages?

Comment: 12/04/2014t14:58. t is printed instead of tab char.

Comment: Did you try it like that `str_replace( '\', '\\', $format ); ` ?

Comment: There is 6-years-old feature request https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43901 for what you are asking. The bad news is that it’s still not implemented. So you are to deal with weird `str_replace('\t', "\t"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can hack around this as follows:

```
$format = 'd/M/Y\tH:i';
$format = str_replace('\t', "\t", $format);
echo date($format);
```

You can see the fiddle [here](http://ideone.com/HvPmZD).

Comment: Your solution works for the problem, I mentioned. But this did not solve my real problem. I assumed that I am getting a single quoted string from oci call. But even after using string replace, it wont work.

Comment: what do you mean by an "oci call" can you show more of your code please?

Comment: what do you get if you just print the format without passing it to `date()`?

Comment: `php > $format = str_replace('\t', "\t", $format);
php > print_r(str_split($format));
Array
(
    [0] => d
    [1] => /
    [2] => M
    [3] => /
    [4] => Y
    [5] =>  
    [6] => H
    [7] => :
    [8] => i
)
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66289/discussion-between-xenres-and-victory).

Answer (score 2):

Other than actually replacing the quote marks, not really. What is actually happening is that the double quotes actually *change* what is inside the string. Specifically, under double quotes the sequence "\t" is converted into the symbol for a tab, while under single quotes they're interpreted as the literal sequence \t.

So what you *could* do is manually replace them, like this:

```
 str_replace( '\t', "\t", $format );
```

But it'd be easier to just enter them as double quoted in the first place.